# Template deduction fails with argument after parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-argument-deduction

I have this function:

```
template <typename... Args>
void f(Args... args, int last)
{
}
```

Template deduction fails if I call it without explicit template parameters:

```
f(2, 2); // candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

But giving the explicit template parameters for the parameter pack works:

```
f<int>(2, 2); // compiles fine
```

Even though logically speaking, the compiler should be able to deduce that the parameter pack consists of all but the last argument types. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[temp.deduct.type]/p5:

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> - [...]
> - A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the *parameter-declaration-list*.

To get deduction, you'll have to do

```
template <typename... Args>
void f(Args... args)
{
}
```

and slice off the last argument in the body, or make `last` `first` instead:

```
template <typename... Args>
void f(int first, Args... args)
{
}
```

It's hard to give more specific advice since we don't know what this function template is supposed to do.

Comment: How would I slice off the last argument most easily, short of packing everything into a tuple, and then unpacking by index?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question.