# Template parameter pack deduction when not passed as last parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename... Args>
void testfunc(const std::function<void (float, Args..., char)>& func)
{

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto func = [](float, int, char) {};
    auto sfunc = static_cast<std::function<void (float, int, char)>>(func);
    testfunc<int>(sfunc);

    return 0;
}
```

I specify the type explicitly because (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40476083):

> When a parameter pack doesn't appear last in the parameter
>   declaration, it is a non-deduced context. A non-deduced context means
>   that the template arguments have to be given explicitly.

MSVC successfully compiles it, while both gcc and clang reject the code:

```
source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
source_file.cpp:14:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘testfunc(std::function<void(float, int, char)>&)’
     testfunc<int>(sfunc);
                        ^
source_file.cpp:5:6: note: candidate: template<class ... Args> void testfunc(const std::function<void(float, Args ..., char)>&)
 void testfunc(const std::function<void (float, Args..., char)>& func)
      ^
source_file.cpp:5:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
source_file.cpp:14:24: note:   mismatched types ‘char’ and ‘int’
     testfunc<int>(sfunc);
                        ^
source_file.cpp:14:24: note:   ‘std::function<void(float, int, char)>’ is not derived from ‘const std::function<void(float, Args ..., char)>’
```

Let's now make a slight change - let's *remove* the `int` argument from our local `func`, thereby causing the template argument pack to become empty:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename... Args>
void testfunc(const std::function<void (float, Args..., char)>& func)
{

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto func = [](float, char) {};
    auto sfunc = static_cast<std::function<void (float, char)>>(func);
    testfunc<>(sfunc);

    return 0;
}
```

This time, all three compilers reject the code as incorrect.
Tested with http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_gcc and a local Visual Studio installation.

**Questions:**

1. Who is correct in the first case?
2. How to achieve the desired effect - i.e., how can I explicitly specify a (possibly empty) parameter pack?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318502/why-is-template-parameter-pack-used-in-a-function-argument-type-as-its-template

Comment: @Rakete1111 - it's seems to me that question 1 is a duplicate; but (IMHO) question 2 isn't.

Comment: @max66 Both cases work with provided workaround (*testfunc<>)(sfunc)

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky - do you mean the solution proposed by Barry? I didn't see it. Wonderful! You (and Rakete1111) are right: duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can block deduction:

```
template<typename... Args>
void testfunc(const block_deduction<std::function<void (float, Args..., char)>>& func)
```

with

```
template<class T>
struct tag_t{using type=T;};

template<class T>
using block_deduction=typename tag_t<T>::type;
```

and now `Args...` is in a non-deduced context.

You can do fancier things with SFINAE and omitting `char` then testing that `char` is at the end of the `Args...`, but that seems overkill.

---

I will bet dollars to donuts that when gcc and clang disagree with MSVC, MSVC isn't right.  But I have not standard delved to confirm that.

Comment: Nice solution, and unlike the solutions suggested in the other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318502/why-is-template-parameter-pack-used-in-a-function-argument-type-as-its-template), it works in MSVC. Could you explain why wrapping the type in what is essentially `std::identity` disables deduction?

Comment: _I will bet dollars to donuts that when gcc and clang disagree with MSVC, MSVC isn't right._ It's worth a +1 more than your good answer. :-)

Comment: @szcur because the standard says that such a type mapping results in a non-deduced context.  I suspect because the general case permits a turing complete type mapping, and inverting a turing complete mapping is impractical.  Rather than spending a bunch of work describing a invertable subset of mappings they just said "no deduction"

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the standard says the deduction of template argument packs must be "greedy", this would make MSVC++ wrong at accepting malformed code.

I don't want to concentrate on whether the compilers are wrong because type packs that are not the last in argument lists are very difficult to work with, so, I would rather focus on side stepping the cases where they arise.

The rules of the language dictate that explicit template arguments in a pack are just the beginning of the pack, not the whole pack, that means autodeduction rules will be activated the same.  On the other hand, autodeduction of template parameters is "greedy", it keeps going regardless of what needs to be satisfied later.  Autodeduction of template parameters do not "backtrack".

A way to sidestep the problem is to disable autodeduction and supply the template arguments explicitly.

What @Yakk does in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45948504/4988044) is to say that the argument type is a member of some template.  At that moment the compiler turns off autodeduction because it can't deduce the template arguments from a member:

```
template<typename... Args>
void test_func(
    const typename block<
        std::function<void(int, Args..., char)>
    >::type &argument
);
```

there, the rules of the language only allow to get the type of `argument` by having the complete template parameter list, there is no deduction possible.  The final type, `typename block<...>::type` happens to be `std::function<void(int, Args..., char)>`, but the compiler can't go from that "result" to the deduce the template arguments that produced it.

The type of `argument` is calculated from the template parameter inputs.